# How to free a linked list's elements and content?

Tags: c, list, malloc

```
// Represents a single list node. The value is dynamically allocated. The node 
// is the owner of the value and has to free it when itself is released.
struct Node {
    String value; // dynamically allocated string, release memory!
    struct Node* next; // self-reference
};
typedef struct Node Node;

// Create a list node. Copies the value (into dynamically allocated storage).
Node* new_node(String value, Node* next) {
    Node* node = xcalloc(1, sizeof(Node));
    node->value = s_copy(value); // s_copy performs dynamic allocation
    node->next = next;
    return node;
}

// Prints the components of the given list.
void print_list(Node* list) {
    if (list == NULL) {
        printf("[]");
    } else {
        printf("[%s", list->value);
        for (Node* n = list->next; n != NULL; n = n->next) {
            printf(" %s", n->value);
        }
        printf("]");
    }
}

// Print list followed by a newline.
void println_list(Node* list) {
    print_list(list);
    printsln("");
}

// Free all nodes of the list, including the values it contains.
void free_list(Node* list) {

    struct node* tmp;

   while (list!= NULL)
    {
       tmp = list;
       list = list->next;
       free(tmp);
    }
}
```

Implement the function free_list, which releases a list with its content. Note that the list is the owner of the list items (value) and all list items are dynamically allocated. So these must also be released.

already created a List Node, Print List, now im on the Third exercise and i need to implement the function free list with the usage of xmalloc, but i dont know how i free a list with xmalloc,there is nothing in my notes i can use, can anyone help me, itried but its not working?

Comment: Are you sure it says to use `xmalloc` and not `xfree`? You can't free anything with `xmalloc` as that is obviously for the allocation part and not the free part. If that isn't the problem then please clarify what "its not working" means exactly.

Comment: It doesnt say i NEED to use xmalloc, it says i need to use it instead of malloc and use xcalloc instead of calloc, also 

I dont even know if i did it right because as i said, there is nothing about free a list in my uni notes, probably just bullshit what i wrote down lol. the error is

assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        tmp = list;
            ^

Comment: If you are asking about that warning then put it into the question. But you didn't show us a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so it is difficult to provide precise help. We don't know what `Node` is but it seems it is not the same as `struct node` and that is what the warning message is saying. Other than that `free_list` looks mostly right except looks like `tmp->value` also needs to be freed.

Comment: I edited, now u can see waht node is sorry :D  oh nice, thanks i accidently wrote it in lowercase , could you maybe show me how i also free tmp->value?

Comment: It needs to be `struct Node *tmp` or `Node *tmp`. Note that capital `N`. `struct node` and `struct Node` are different. To free value just do `xfree(tmp->value)`

Comment: yeah i noticed and forgot to write it in the text and now editet it. Where do i write xfree(tmp->value) ? just at the bottom or?

Comment: `xmalloc` and `xcalloc` are generally just wrappers around `malloc` and `calloc` that validate the return. I haven't seen an `xfree` as there is no validation and it would be pointless to set the local pointer to `NULL` within an `xfree`. You call `free` on your allocated block of memory when you are through using the allocated block. You can put that wherever is appropriate. A short example with strings is [Singly Linked List of Strings With Sorted Insertion](https://pastebin.com/PechfyQa)

Comment: yeah i dont even know waht xfree does and i have no xfree in my programm, now i get bunch of errors saying "undefined reference to `xfree'" or "implicit declaration of function 'xfree'"

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: If `xfree` is implemented as a macro, it could either `NULL` out as part of the macro itself, or pass the address of the macro argument to the `xfree` implementation function to allow the same behavior.

Comment: Then just call `free(tmp->value)`. Goes right before `free(tmp)`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger - ooh, correct. Hadn't thought about a macro.

Comment: `  struct Node* tmp;
   
   while (list!= NULL)
    {
       tmp = list;
       list = list->next;
    free(tmp->value);
       free(tmp);
    }
 ` My code now looks like this, but now when i in the free(tmp->value); it doesnt start without an error

Comment: What does "it doesn't start" mean? You really need to be a bit more precise with your descriptions.

Comment: Okay, sorry english is my third language and i always use basic terms for some reason, i mean there is no output in the console, https://gyazo.com/44896e422f43455c9348ff223bc0f551 It should be like this, but when i put in the free(tmp->value) it just doenst write anything inthe console, if i put it without the  free(tmp->value); there are only 20 Memory leaks instead of 46. 

And i need to get it down to 0 Memory leaks

Comment: Now you are talking about things that we can't see. We have no idea how your assignment is set up and what that output means. Without a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I think I have reached the limit of what I can help you with as it is not productive to try and understand code I can't see or run. Good luck!

Comment: @kaylum The code above is legit the whole thing, "In this task, various functions are to be implemented on a simply linked list with elements of the type string." and my exercise is Implement the function free_list, which releases a list with its content. Note that the list is the owner of the list items (value) and all list items are dynamically allocated. So these must also be released. Thats all, now i dont know any less than u :D

Comment: I know it's legit. But it is not complete. For example, I don't know the sequence of the function calls. And I can't run it to check what else could be wrong that is causing other problems. There's only so much one can do by just looking at the code (and incomplete to boot). If you read the link I gave that explains why MVEs are important and a requirement for Stackoverflow questions.

Comment: @kaylum , now i moved the free(tmp->value); after the free(tmp) and now i get an output and there is only 12 memory leaks left, idk why it doesnt work when i put it before free(tmp)

Comment: No No No. Don't do that. That is undefined behaviour as `tmp` is already freed memory when you dereference it in `tmp->value`. And before you say "but it works" please understand that undefined behaviour means that the result is unpredictable including sometimes appearing to "work". But it will just blow up at some unexpected time and place. Just think about it logically, if you free something then it doesn't make sense to use it anymore as you've effectively destroyed it.

Comment: When program behaviour changes due to moving seemingly unrelated code around then it means you have bugs else where resulting in undefined behaviour. Don't make  the code wrong just because it appears to make the program behave "better". You need to find the real bug.

Comment: well yeah thanks for ur help ^^ i hope i can find some help because there is legit nothing about freeing lists in our notes